# In C++ how to reset variables in a class after X seconds?

Tags: c++, multithreading, reset

I need to reset some values in a class after  X seconds pass. I am using something like this, but I don't know what problems it might have:

```
class Points
{
    public:
        Points();
        ~Points();
        void reset();
        ...
    private:
        int number;
        static void resetAfter5seconds(Points* points);
};
```

Inside the contructor I initialize a detached thread:

```
Points::Points(){
    thread start(resetAfter5seconds, this);
    start.detach();
}

void Points::resetAfter5seconds(Points* points){

   while(true){
     std::this_thread::sleep_for( (std::chrono::seconds(5)));
     points->reset();
   }

}
```

This works but I dont know if it is the right approach. Does it have any memory problems?, what are the alternatives?

Comment: nit-picking: you might want to put a mutex around whatever you want to reset in another thread.

Comment: You don't need a `static` thread function, just use a normal member function.

Comment: If this Points object is ever deleted, the reset thread will still try to access it causing an access violation. To fix this, you need to use the destructor to communicate to the reset thread that it's time to stop looping. Wait for the thread to close before returning from the destructor.

Comment: Never use a detached thread, unless you know what you are doing. Here the thread will operate on a dangling pointer as soon as the `Points` are destructed.

Comment: @lorro -- that is not  nit-picking at all, but the basis of everything that is wrong with this implementation -- it is not threadsafe.

Comment: Are you sure you want values that reset after 5 seconds? You got a whole bunch of problems. Usually you can only make sure that they will reset after AT LEAST 5 seconds. What happens to a user thats in the middle of using the values?!

Comment: A thread is not required for this.  Can you add code to the getter for Points that performs the reset (on the caller's thread) after the time has elapsed?

Comment: @DieterLücking I have not have this problem (yet) MAYBE because I am only using one instance of Points that last during the entire run, but I agree it is something that may cause trouble in another scenario.

Comment: @Anxious -- Thread-safety problem are trolls that stick their head up when you least want them to -- it is easy (relatively) to run entire development cycles without ever seeing any only to find it all crash-and-burn once used in production.  Reason being that your development system is lightly used compared to something in production, and thread-safety issues are probabilistic in nature

Comment: At the very least, you probably want to make `number` a `std::atomic<int>` instead of `int`

Answer (score 5):

Your code is not thread safe, and making it thread safe is probably too much to do if the rest of the code is single threaded.  Maybe you could have a simpler pattern that does not require a threaded function, like just checking if the time of 5 sec has elapsed since the creation, something like this;

```
class Points
{
public:
    Points() {creationtime = time(0); /* do the rest of init */ }
    ~Points();
    void method1() { test_and_reset(); /* do the rest of logic...*/ }
    void method2() { test_and_reset(); /* do the rest of logic...*/ }

        ...
private:
    time_t creationtime;
    void test_and_reset() {
          time_t now = time(0);
          if (now > creationtime + 5) { /*reset*/ }
    }
};
```

The above simple implementation also mean that you will not have the problem of the thread accessing invalid memory once the object is deleted, and you will not have to figure out how to kill the tread.

Comment: Its impossible to tell if the OPs code is thread safe as he doesn't show the implementation of `Point` -- as long as `reset` and all other member functions of `Point` contain the necessary mutexes or atomic accesses, it might well be.

Comment: @ChrisDodd -- true, but judging from the comments and replies it is not threadsafe

Comment: It's not exactly what I need right now but this is a good alternative for another class I have. Does it have any downsides?

Answer (score 5):

Do it lazily. No need for threads here. Add getter (private or public), and only access the variable through  the  getter (and corresponding setter, probably).

In the getter, check if reset time is active (simple boolean flag to minimize overhead) and then check if enough time has passed and then reset the value. Finally return the value as in a simple getter.

---

Or, if your application has event loop and event driven architecture (probably not, just adding this here for completeness), add timer event to reset the value. Still no need for threads to complicate matrers.

Comment: Yes, event driven is the way to go.